# How would I specifically target users who have not used my app in several days?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm a fairly new iOS developer (started from scratch 3 months ago) and I've recently submitted my first app to the App Store. In my upcoming update I would like to incorporate push notifications, and have decided to use Parse. I am looking for a way to send push notifications through Parse to users who, for example (and for the purposes of this question), have not used my app for 10 days or more. If possible, I am hoping to be able to send the notifications through the web console using the segment feature. I assume I should be able to do this using the updatedAt property to check when is the last time the user launched the app, but I'm at a loss on how to programmatically implement this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could create a new field namely LastLogin in which you would store the date and time of user whenever he/she login your app. So with this lastLogin you calculate a time interval and fire a push notification.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still a little confused with regards to how to create this LastLogin field. Would you be able to provide me with an example?

Comment: I guess below answer provided by is good. So u could go with this one and let me know if anything else is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else wondering how to do this, I figured out how without any additional code than what is already provided in the SDK integration guide. When sending a push notification through the Parse Push web console, you can choose Segment instead of Everyone, in the "Send To" field and then a new field appears to set the conditions that the installation must match. There are 9 options in this field: parseVersion, appName, appVersion, timeZone, badge, appIdentifier, channels, createdAt, updatedAt. What I failed to realize at first is that the currentInstallation objected created by this code directly from the SDK

`PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
currentInstallation.channels = @[@"global"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];`

is created once on initial launch (the date/time the app is first launched is set to the createdAt property), and then each time the app is launched the currentInstallation object's updatedAt property gets updated to the current date/time. So, to send a notification to users who have not used your app in, say, 10 days, through the web console, you would choose "Segment" from the "Send To" field, and then for the current installation conditions you would choose "updatedAt" and enter a date in the box that corresponds to at least 10 days ago.